# How to press Enter after entering text in a text field?

Tags: python, selenium, autoit

I tried to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after entering text in a text field using AutoIt:

```
from time import sleep
import ait

ait.move(557, 335) // the position of text field
ait.click()
sleep(3)
ait.write('34117')
sleep(3)
ait.press('Enter')
```

[image: The target part of website]

The value 34117 is correctly entered but when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button is pressed, an error arises:

> File "E:\python\scraping\hrsde\scraper.py", line 55, in scraper
> ait.press('Enter')   File "C:\Users\Charlie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ait_windows.py",
> line 644, in press
> inputs = [i for key in keys for i in _key_as_kbd_inputs(key)]   File
> "C:\Users\Charlie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ait_windows.py",
> line 644, in 
> inputs = [i for key in keys for i in _key_as_kbd_inputs(key)]   File
> "C:\Users\Charlie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ait_windows.py",
> line 339, in _key_as_kbd_inputs
> vks = list(map(_key_to_vk, key.split('+')))   File "C:\Users\Charlie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ait_windows.py",
> line 318, in _key_to_vk
> raise ValueError('Unknown key {!r}'.format(key)) from None ValueError: Unknown key 'ENTER'

Answer (score 1):

You can find that info in the github code

use '\n' for return key

[autoit github](https://github.com/Lonami/autoit/blob/master/ait/_linux.py)

In the KEYS dict you can see that '\n' is translated to xdotool key "Return"